# Read hard disk performance active time

Tags: python, windows, psutil

Work on a monitoring application to monitor the performance of the processor and the hard disk

The processor performance check part was simple using `psutil`

But it is difficult to get information about the performance of the hard disk from this library

I tried to go to the traditional methods, but the cost was great in performance

I want to get something like this
`Disk in/out: XX MB/s` and `Disk active time: XX%` like in Windows resources monitor

`psutil` return sdiskio contain

`(read_count=xxxx, write_count=xxxx, read_bytes=xxxx, write_bytes=xxx, read_time=xxxx, write_time=xxx)`

I cannot determine through these numbers the active time of the hard drive
[image]

---

**#update**

what I'm tried so far

```
while(True):
    disk_io_counter = psutil.disk_io_counters(perdisk=True)['PhysicalDrive1']
    disk_read_bytes = disk_io_counter[2]  # read_bytes 
    disk_write_bytes = disk_io_counter[3] #  write_byte
    disk_read_time = disk_io_counter[4]  # read_time
    disk_write_time = disk_io_counter[5] #  write_time
    time.sleep(1)
    disk_io_counter = psutil.disk_io_counters(perdisk=True)['PhysicalDrive1']
    disk_read_bytes1 = disk_io_counter[2]   # read_bytes 
    disk_write_bytes1 = disk_io_counter[3] #  write_byte
    disk_read_time1 = disk_io_counter[4]  # read_time
    disk_write_time1 = disk_io_counter[5] #  write_time


    total_read = disk_read_bytes1 -disk_read_bytes 
    total_write = disk_write_bytes1 - disk_write_bytes
    total_read_time = disk_read_time1 -disk_read_time 
    total_write_time = disk_write_time1 - disk_write_time


    print("Read : ",bytes2human( total_read) )
    print("Write : ",bytes2human( total_write) )

    print("Time_Read : ",total_read_time )
    print("Time_Write : ",total_write_time )
```

that gives me the right read and write speed but still nothing about the actual percentage